# How set image on slider?

Tags: iphone, uislider, slidetoggle

[image]

I want to use slider control for above image. When user slide then category tab become highlighted and all delighted. So how I use slider controller so that i can get this functionality? How use  slider control for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
The simplest solution would be to render a UIImage behind the control to represent the track. The thumbknob can be changed with:

[mySlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

A side-effect of this is that the track isn't rendered unless you provide your own. This, combined with the UIImage, provide you with a custom UISlider without you having to subclass anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

The control you are showing is a segment control and you can set the image by using this piece of code

```
UISegmentedControl* offlineSegment=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ON",@"OFF",nil] autorelease]];
    [offlineSegment setFrame:CGRectMake(210,50,90,30)];
    offlineSegment.tintColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    offlineSegment.selectedSegmentIndex=0;

    offlineSegment.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
    [locationSegment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"onSelected.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [locationSegment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [offlineSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(offlineSetting:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:offlineSegment];
    [offlineSegment release];
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: i have required slider with this.

Comment: Fine,then you need to subclass UIView class and need to draw slider there.Then you can achieve this else its not easy without using custom implementation

Comment: can u give code for how customize slider and add with segment control?

Comment: Well robin have give the link to download code below.You can get the idea from here how to customize that.Even that code is also helpful if you have checked that...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will answer your question or not but I have seen this project of github that looks someWhat like this

https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl